# Reload page after reactive form submission inside a dialog

Tags: angular, forms, dialog, submit, reload

I have an Angular reactive form inside a dialog component. The dialog component is opened from a page component which is routed as '/mypage'. I want my page to be reloaded when the form is submitted so a given table inside my page is refreshed with the data posted to the backend from the form.

The mypage is not being reloaded after submission so I don't see the new posted data.

In addition to the following code, I tried using `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` to the app-routing module imports, and so `routerLink="/mypage"` to the submission button of the form, but it neither reloads the mypage.

Which other approach should be considered?

*dialog.component.html*

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <form [formGroup]="newGroupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveNewGroup()">

        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between space-between">

            <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline"
            fxFlex>
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <mat-hint>Group Name</mat-hint>
                <input matInput formControlName="groupname">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline"
            fxFlex>
                <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
                <mat-hint>Group Description</mat-hint>
                <textarea matInput formControlName="groupdescription"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

        </div>
        
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close type="submit">Save</button>
        
    </form>
</div>
```

*dialog.component.ts*

```
...
  export class NewGroupDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.newGroupForm = new FormGroup({
      'groupname': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'groupdescription': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  newGroupForm: FormGroup;

  onSaveNewGroup() {
    const body = {
      "name": this.newGroupForm.value.groupname,
      "description": this.newGroupForm.value.groupdescription
    }

    this.apiService.postGroup(body)
    .subscribe(group => {
      
    })
  }

}
```

*mypage.component.html*

```
...
                <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="primary"
                    (click)="onCreateGroup()">
                    New Group
                </button>
```

*mypage.component.ts*

```
  ...
  onCreateGroup() {
    let dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig
    dialogConfig.height = "80vh"
    dialogConfig.width = "80vw"
    this.newGroupDialog.open(NewGroupDialogComponent, dialogConfig)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be because of RouteReuseStrategy.

Let's try a quick dirty approach to make sure it's because of the reuse strategy; Add this to your component's ngOnInit():

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  /* prevent angular from reusing the same route. */
  this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

If it worked then implement your custom RouteReuseStrategy and add it to your module.ts file:

```js
providers: [
    {
        provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
        useClass: CustomRoutingReuseStrategy
    }
]
```

For more information check [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy)

Comment: I added the ngOnInit to the mypage.component.ts as you suggested, including the routerLink="/mypage" in the dialog.component.html, but it didn't work. It is strange because the routerLink works indeed (I checked by simply routing to "/myhome" instead).

Comment: oh my god, I don't understand but I made it works. I simply change the way of routing: instead of using the routerLink in the dialog component, I added this._router.navigateByUrl('/mypage') in the onSaveNewGroup() method of the dialog.component.ts ....  What is the difference?

Answer (score -2):

After the request to the server is complete, just call `window.location.reload();` and it will make your page refresh

Comment: Hi we tried that it doesn’t work. Wrong answer